# mathpartir: ottalt puts mathpartir premises each on their own line

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs, automation, fractions

I'm using the Ott tool to generate LaTeX for some inference rules in a Programming Language paper. To make the output look good, I'm using the [OttAlt](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~jesse/code/latex/ottalt/ottalt.pdf) library.

OttAlt is based on mathpartir, and one of its main features is that it can automatically add line-breaks between premises, so that short ones are all on the same line, but long ones get broken up.

The problem is, when I use OttAlt, it seems to always put each premise on its own line, even when I choose the `implicitPremiseBreaks` option.

The problem looks to be with the [ottpremise](https://github.com/tov/latex-ottalt/blob/master/ottalt.dtx#L945) and [ottdefnblock](https://github.com/tov/latex-ottalt/blob/master/ottalt.dtx#L981) macros redefinitions.

Does anyone have an idea of why ottAlt would be breaking the automatic spacing of premises?

I'd really rather not have to manually insert all my line breaks, but I'd also like to get the space savings of putting small premises on one line.

[Here's a MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rnyypfxcyzph). It depends on non-CTAN packages, so I can't have a self-hosted MWE, but here's the main file:

```
%% Generated from the following Ott file:


% metavar exprvar, x, y, f ::= 
%    {{ coq nat }} {{ coq-equality }} 
%   {{ tex \mathit{[[exprvar]]} }} {{ com  term variable  }} {{ lex alphanum }} {{ texvar \mathtt{[[exprvar]]} }}


% grammar


% e,t  :: tm_ ::= {{ com terms }}
%   | x            ::   :: var  {{ com variable }}


% G  :: env_ ::= {{ com typing contexts }}
%   | empty        ::   :: nil  {{ com empty }}

% defns Jtype :: '' ::=

% defn G |- e : t :: :: typing :: T_ {{ com term typing }} by


% G |- x : t
% G |- x : t
% G |- x : t
% G |- x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 : t
% ---------- :: Var
% G |- x : t



\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpartir}



\usepackage[implicitPremiseBreaks]{ottalt}


\inputott{ott_out}

% \renewcommand{\ottpremise}[1]{#1}


\begin{document}

OttAlt:

%Doesn't work, puts each on its own line
\ottdefntyping{foo}

MathPartir:

\begin{mathpar}
\inferrule{G |-x : t \\ G |-x : t \\ G |-x : t \\ G |-x_{1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111} : t }{Foo}
\end{mathpar}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Good question - but very specialized, probably not many people here know how to answer it. You could try to ask the package author, for example by creating an issue on the [Github page](https://github.com/tov/latex-ottalt) of the package.

Comment: @Marijn true that its specialized, I was mostly hoping somebody could help me make heads or tail of what the macros are doing. The GitHub hasn't had an update in 5 years, so I'm not holding my breath on feedback...

Comment: It seems like Jesse Tov is on the case :) if the issue is resolved (or if no solution can be found) please post it here as well for future visitors.